# How to disable bash info prints

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im running the next postgres query using the next bash command.

```
sudo -u postgres bash -c "psql -d db -c \"SELECT ip FROM db_accounts;\"" \>/dev/null
```

The output is a table but before the table is printed, I get the following info prints

```
> psql: /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10: no version information available
> (required by psql) psql: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: no version
> information available (required by /usr/pgsql-9.4/lib/libpq.so.5)
> psql: /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10: no version information available
> (required by /usr/pgsql-9.4/lib/libpq.so.5)
```

I want to run my command without these prints appearing.

I tried to change the end of the command >/dev/null to 2>/dev/null  and indeed the prints were disable but my table was not fully displayed (out of 800 rows only 40 were displayed),
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--quiet` when you start psql

**OR**

It can be set in your `postgresql.conf` file by adding this

```
client_min_messages = warning
```

This [blog](http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2010/03/running-sql-scripts-with-psql.html) is really helpful.

Comment: I added the --quiet like this sudo -u postgres bash -c "psql --quiet -d db -c \"SELECT ip FROM db_accounts;\"" \>/dev/null  and I still see those prints

Comment: But I entered the blog you attached and I found the solution there so Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

To fix want I wanted I added --pset pager=off to the psql to get the whole table and the disable the prints I change the end of the command to 2>/dev/null

final command:
sudo -u postgres bash -c "psql --pset pager=off --quiet -d db -c \"SELECT ip FROM db_accounts;\"" 2>/dev/null